# How my win form application can interact with signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, signalr

I develop an asp.net & signalr based chat apps where people can send message to specific user.

Now I want to develop a win form chat apps which will connect to my asp.net based signalr hub and fetch all logged in users and display those user in a grid.

So just tell me is it at all feasible by signalr that winform & web form users can talk to each other but my signalr hub will be only in web. If yes, then please guide me how to develop such apps with winform because web part is ready.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine Thanks for that. I really would not mind as long as they left a reason why they down voted. I am always willing to learn and adapt but just down voting does not 'add' anything to the process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitul Suther has a [blog](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.nl/2012/12/testing-signalr-in-wpf-console-and.html) about using SignalR in WPF